# Historic roadworks

Tags: historical

As part of a research effort, I am working on the recognition of roadworks from street-level imagery. On top of other sources, we have the plan to match historic street view snapshots with roadworks data in order to get a geographically diverse dataset. However, datasets seem to be sparse. We need three attributes: location (preferably XY), start date, and end date.
The only concrete dataset which suits my needs is the historic [Vicroads](https://www.data.vic.gov.au/data/dataset/road-works-and-events-points-snapshot/resource/5791314b-fb70-41ae-800f-e3e260265872) snapshot.

After some digging, I can't seem to find other sources like it. OpenStreetMap has the `construction` tag but doesn't have a proper protocol for roadworks. Not to mention, searching the entire history of OSM snapshots requires a lot of set-ups.

Does anyone have any other suggestions on sources I could check out?

EDIT: For anyone stumbling in here in the future, I'll post any suitable working links I can find.
[Leeds roadworks from the backup site](https://old.datahub.io/dataset/de2d6895-fd5b-4912-9563-6eedff07d245)

Answer (score 2):

This dataset is literally called "historic roadworks"

https://data.gov.uk/dataset/historic-roadworks

> Data related to historic roadworks across Leeds. Automated update This dataset is updated automatically on the 1st day of each quarter.

---

In general, this kind of dataset would be more likely to be found from a local municipality (city) rather than global.

Comment: I did find that one, and the problem with it is that the download link is dead. Also, there are not very many like it, and the ones that are out there are very short-lived. Thanks in any case, I'll have to do some thinking on which sources I could include instead.